# Why do these two expressions evaluate to different values?

Tags: java

I can't seem to find why these two expressions evaluate to different results.  Can someone enlighten me?

```
double var1 = 53, var2 = 51.95;
int res1 = (int)((var1 - var2)*100);
int res2 = (int)(var1*100 - var2*100);

Output: res1 = 104   res2 = 105
```

Comment: Try printing out some intermediate values (`var1`, `var2`, `(var1 - var2)*100` and `var1*100-var2*100`) using `System.out.printf("%24.20f\n")`. The results should explain what's happening.  Also, this question gets asked extremely frequently here.  Next time please search more diligently before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating points can't exactly store all values, and in particular they can't exactly store all decimal values. 51.95 can't be stored in a `double` -- what you're really storing is something *close* to that value. When you multiply the almost-but-not-quite value by 100, you magnify that error. `res1` and `res2` do that in slightly different ways, so it shouldn't be surprising that they get slightly different results.

Here's a bit more detail.

You can use [this converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to figure out what a double's value really is. For instance, 51.95 has a binary representation of `01000010010011111100110011001101` and corresponds to the decimal number 51.95000076293945. That's the *real* value of `var2`; it's the closest number to 51.95 that a double can represent. `var1` is just what it looks like, 53.

So, let's look at `res1` first. 53 - 51.95000076293945 is 1.04999923706055. Using that converter, we see that this value can't be exactly stored in a double; what you'll actually get it 1.0499992. Multiply that by 100 and you get 104.99992, which truncates to an int 104.

Now `res2`. 53*100 is 5300, and 51.95000076293945*100 is 5195.000076293945, which is really 5195.0. 5300-5195.0 is 105.

Comment: Thanks for the link and answer.